# google.auth.exceptions.DefaultCredentialsError:

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-translate

So, I am following the same procedure exactly according to the Google Translate API's Documentation.

The code below was provided in it.

```
# Imports the Google Cloud client library

from google.cloud import translate

# Instantiates a client
translate_client = translate.Client()

# The text to translate
text = u'Hello, world!'
# The target language
target = 'ru'

# Translates some text into Russian
translation = translate_client.translate(
    text,
    target_language=target)

print(u'Text: {}'.format(text))
print(u'Translation: {}'.format(translation['translatedText']))
```

Now when I run this I am returned with the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "test.py", line 5, in <module>
    translate_client = translate.Client()   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\google\cloud\translate_v2\client.py", line 65, in __init__
    super(Client, self).__init__(credentials=credentials, _http=_http)   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\google\cloud\client.py", line 129, in __init__
    credentials, _ = google.auth.default()   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\google\auth\_default.py", line 294, in default
    credentials, project_id = checker()   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\google\auth\_default.py", line 165, in _get_explicit_environ_credentials
    os.environ[environment_vars.CREDENTIALS])   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\google\auth\_default.py", line 89, in _load_credentials_from_file
    'File {} was not found.'.format(filename)) google.auth.exceptions.DefaultCredentialsError: File  D:\Summer Projects\Translate\social media analysis-2a59d94ba22d.json was not found.
```

The `D:\Summer Projects\Translate\social media analysis-2a59d94ba22d.json` is the path where I put my key provided by Google Cloud for this project.

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Your need to set an environment variable for `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`

You can add this in your code by adding in the following lines:

```
credential_path = "D:\Summer Projects\Translate\social media analysis-2a59d94ba22d.json"
os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = credential_path
```

Complete solution:

```
# Imports the Google Cloud client library

import os    
from google.cloud import translate

credential_path = "D:\Summer Projects\Translate\social media analysis-2a59d94ba22d.json"
os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = credential_path

# Instantiates a client
translate_client = translate.Client()

# The text to translate
text = u'Hello, world!'
# The target language
target = 'ru'

# Translates some text into Russian
translation = translate_client.translate(
    text,
    target_language=target)

print(u'Text: {}'.format(text))
print(u'Translation: {}'.format(translation['translatedText']))
```

Comment: Additionally, you can find more information about how to set up authentication for Client Libraries in [this documentation link](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/reference/libraries#setting_up_authentication).

Answer (score 1):

If setting from command prompt:

```
SET GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=C:\work\xxxba6.json
```

**Note: Do not put quotes in the path "C:\work\xxxba6.json".**

Google Python scripts cannot handle it.

Answer (score 0):

I am now dealing with the vision API.
My solution is depend on the answer above.

But the sample code from google is a little bit different with previous code.

For my sample code is

```py
def run_quickstart():
    import os
    import io
    from google.cloud import vision
    from google.cloud.vision import types
    ...

    # I made the modification here
    credential_path = "PATH"

    # for example
    # credential_path = "projectname-xxxxxxxx.json"

    # WRONG code
    # credential_path = "~/Downloads/projectname-xxxxxxxx.json"


    os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = credential_path
```

The things need to noticed is that I put the `JSON` file into the same folder as `.py`
so the `PATH` is not actually a real path to point the JSON file
It's only goes to the name of the JSON file, like this `projectname-xxxxxxxx.json`

Answer (score 0):

If you work on linux, just put this in your python code:

```
os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = "./Authentication.json"
```